# Multiple promise errors (promises must be constructed via new)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to create two asynch promises in my node app, to return all of the latestDeploymentDate(s) as they are fetched from an external API. I previously did this without promises, however I could not return all of the latestDeploymentDate(s) to the mapped array, because it was out of scope. Therefore I followed a JavaScript promises tutorial found on google, however I have been unsuccessful implementing it. Please find the code and the stack trace below:

```
const express = require('express')();
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');
const ta = require('time-ago')();
var promise = require('promise')()

const webApplications = require('./account.json');
var newArr = new Array();


express.listen(3001, function() {

  console.log('Server is listening...');
  express.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    res.json(webApplications.map((item, latestDeploymentDate) => {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
        // return 'foo';
      const newRelicRequest = {
        url: `https://XXX`,
        headers: {
          'X-Api-Key': 'XXX'
        }
      }
      const gitlabRequest = {
        url: `XXX`,
        headers: {
          'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'XXX'
        }
      }
      var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(newRelicRequest,(err, resp, body) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(body);
          const latestDeployment = data.deployments[0];
          latestDeploymentDate = new Date(latestDeployment.timestamp);
          console.log(new Date(latestDeployment.timestamp));
          resolve(body);
      });

        var secondaryPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          request(gitlabRequest, (err, resp, body) => {
            const gitlabData = JSON.parse(body);
            const currentTag = latestDeployment.description;
            var currentIndex;

        console.log(`${item.appName}` + ' ');
        console.log(`Last deployed: ${latestDeployment.description}
          on ${moment(latestDeploymentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`);

          gitlabData.find((item, index) => {
            currentIndex = index;
            return item.name == currentTag
          });
          if (currentIndex > 3) {
            console.log(`This ${currentIndex} was released ${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
            resolve(latestDeploymentDate);
          } else {
${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
                console.log(`This ${currentIndex} was released ${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
                resolve(latestDeploymentDate);
              }
            })
            })
            promise.then(function(result){
            console.log(result)
            })
          });
        }));
      });
    })
```

Comment: Where's the stacktrace :) ?

Comment: var promise = new Promise(...   var secondaryPromise = new Promise(  ... You have just created two promises that run in parallel, nothing is waiting for anything etc. is that what you intended.

Comment: at the top of the file you have `var promise = require('promise')()` - and then you never use that - just remove that line for a start, `Promise` is native now

Comment: hmm okay, well in that case I am very unsure on how to actually do a promise correctly. How would I go about creating a promise to do what i described above.

Comment: okay removed `var promise = require('promise')()` and now it returns 5 null values

Comment: `now it returns 5 null values` - what is "it" that returns these null values?

Comment: @Jaromanda-x I have read some, however I am in need of further help so hence why I have posted.

Comment: 'it' is the program I am executing

Comment: right - surprised it runs at all since there's syntax errors in the code you posted

Comment: You could really tidy thing's up here, placing stuff in functions like say, -> getRelic, getGitlab etc, would really make things easier to follow.  Also one of the main benefits of Promise's is error propagation,.. in your code you have resolve(body), but if there is an error it will silently disappear.  A simple fix is to have if (err) return reject(err), at the start of the procedure.  As you use promises more and more, using constructor forms will be less needed, as the tools you use might already be promisified.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute one promise after the other in a predictable order, you want to chain them:

```
promise()
|-----------------|
                  secondarypromise(promiseResult)
                  |------------------|
                                     finalHandler(secondayPromiseResult)
                                     |------------------|
```

In your code you can do this like so:

```
promise()
    .then(secondaryPromise) 
    .then(finalHandler);
```

**Note**: I see that you are using `request` which is doesn't support Promises. May I recommend `request-promise` - that way you only need one library for your API calls. `request-promise` is just like `request` but it implements everything based on the Promises API.

Comment: True. But these libraries provide very nice abstraction, which is why they are so popular

Comment: okay so your code has worked to an extent, so thanks for your answer, however now some of my items are undefined such as `const currentTag = latestDeployment.description;` and `latestDeployment`.

Comment: It's inside another function, so it will be undefined.. Either make a closure of you functions, eg. Promise inside a Promise, or pass down the values to the promises via the resolve.